# Clone LI div so it is placed after the original LI instead of end

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to be able to click on an item and clone it immediately after that item, At moment it always Clones to the END, id adds it after the last LI in list.
I created a jsFiddle here [jsfiddle test](https://jsfiddle.net/CheetahTen/16omxvLp/)

**JS**

```
const curId = 20;

function cloneIt(){
  var newId = Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000) + 1);
    const newCloned = $('#d'+curId).clone(true).prop('id', "d"+newId );
    newCloned.html(newCloned.html().replace(
    new RegExp(curId, 'g'),
    newId
    ));

    $("#ulContainer").append(newCloned);
}


$('#ulContainer').on('click', '.tog', function(e) {
  cloneIt();
  alert('item cloned');
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

**HTML**

```
<ul id='ulContainer'>
<li id="d20" class="cards__item">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card__content cellb">
            <a id="dup20" class="tog" href="http://test/pgdup/20">
                <div class="dup20">clone me</div>
            </a>
        </div>

        <div class="card__content nick">
            <p class="card__text nick">Test Tres (20)</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
<li id="d21" class="cards__item">

    <div class="card">
        <div class="card__content anchor">
            <a id="dup21" class="tog" href="http://test/pgdup/21">
                <div class="dup21">clone me</div>
            </a>
        </div>

        <div class="card__content nick">
            <p class="card__text nick">Test Tres (21)</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using [`.after()`](https://api.jquery.com/after/) by passing the *event* to the function:

> Insert content, specified by the parameter, after each element in the set of matched elements.

Change

```
$("#ulContainer").append(newCloned);
```

To

```
$(e.target.closest('li')).after(newCloned);
```

```js
const curId = 20;

function cloneIt(e){
  var newId = Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000) + 1);
    const newCloned = $('#d'+curId).clone(true).prop('id', "d"+newId );
    newCloned.html(newCloned.html().replace(
    new RegExp(curId, 'g'),newId));
    $(e.target.closest('li')).after(newCloned);
}


$('#ulContainer').on('click', '.tog', function(e) {
  cloneIt(e);
  alert('item cloned');
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id='ulContainer'>
<li id="d20" class="cards__item">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card__content cellb">
            <a id="dup20" class="tog" href="http://test/pgdup/20">
                <div class="dup20">clone me</div>
            </a>
        </div>

        <div class="card__content nick">
            <p class="card__text nick">Test Tres (20)</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
<li id="d21" class="cards__item">

    <div class="card">
        <div class="card__content anchor">
            <a id="dup21" class="tog" href="http://test/pgdup/21">
                <div class="dup21">clone me</div>
            </a>
        </div>

        <div class="card__content nick">
            <p class="card__text nick">Test Tres (21)</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: That Places it always After the First LI. So if you click on the second LIm then it places it above. Same with clicking on clones...all of them get places after the first onem instead of the one that was clicked

Comment: @Cheetah, I have updated the answer, please check:)